# Link sound input to specific output device with java api

Tags: java, windows, javasound

I am trying to perform a simple task, select an input device and set the output device.

The use case is as follows, I have 3.5mm jacks and my user can select the output device (headphones or speaker) from a list.

I can play a sound on a given device (with clip), I can control the input device (mute/volume), but I haven't found any way to specify the target line, it's always the system default.

I can get the mixer

```
Optional<Mixer.Info> optJackInMixerInfo = Arrays.stream(AudioSystem.getMixerInfo())
        .filter(mixerInfo -> {
            // Filter based on the device name. 
        })
        .findFirst();
Mixer m = AudioSystem.getMixer(jackInMixerInfo);
```

// The target

```
Line.Info[] lineInfos = m.getTargetLineInfo();
for (Line.Info lineInfo : lineInfos) {
  m.getLine(lineInfo);
  System.out.println("ici");
}
```

I got only the "master volume control".

How can I select the output device ? I can be happy with changing the system default device too.

Answer (score 0):

The naming of `TargetDataLine` and `SourceDataLine` is kind of backwards. Outputs to the local sound system for playback are directed to a `SourceDataLine` and inputs to Java like microphone lines use `TargetDataLine`. I used to know why they were named this way but it's slipped my mind at the moment.

There is a tutorial [Accessing Audio System Resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/accessing.html) with specifics.

Most computers only have a limited number of float controls available, with "master volume" being the one most likely to be implemented. You would use this to alter the volume of the output. Another tutorial in the series, [Processing Audio with Controls](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/controls.html) covers this topic. For myself, I generally convert the audio stream to PCM and handle volume directly (multiply each value by a factor that ranges from 0 to 1) and then convert back to a byte stream, rather than rely on controls which may or may not be present.

Comment: I think I understand the weird naming of this API... At least enough to get control over devices. I have already read, and test the documentation you have provided. My problem is really how to redirect one line to another, because I can control both separately. I thought of your solution with re-encoding, but my device is very slow and I want to avoid this solution if possible. (I did a workaround where I call a batch script that selects the default device). This works, but is not very elegant...

Comment: AFAIK, it is possible to read from a `TargetDataLine` and write the data directly to a `SourceDataLine`, which can be done in a while loop, as long as the read and write sizes are the same and the audio format of each line is the same. But IDK what the performance will be like, as both SDL and TDL make use of blocking queues. Could have a problem with dropouts.

Comment: I once wrote code to take input from a microphone and play it back over the laptop's speakers as an echo (using a circular queue for the delay). One of the keys was to make use of a concurrent-safe FIFO queue to function as a buffer to handle the start-stop nature of the incoming and outgoing data. For multiple echoes, I converted the mic data to PCM, as directly adding the audio bytes will not work when the audio format requires more than 8 bits.

Comment: Yes, this can be a functional workaround, but as my software is the only one to run on the system, I prefer to change the default windows sound device. This is working because it's the only usage I have when I must bind one input to output. All my other usages use binding from buffer.